Angular 16 load component as overay
I have one scenario where I need to load component dynamically from left to right slidIn over another component. As you can see in image at top I have multiple icons which will open different component it can be table/form/list anything.
The problem is I have 20-30 icons that loading based on different situation and the overlay components are currently loading from chart component by ngIf animation left -> right(Stackblitz) and data is share via @Input @Output between overlay component and chart component. This cause chart component class to contain very large code structure and also html file contains large HTML and it became very complex structure.
How can I split this in small structures and optimize so that it will become more readable and clean code ? Is there any way I can load component using ng-content with sharing data between component ?


More questions should be like this, clear explanation and a minimal code example! Kudos to you!

We can approach this problem by using the ng-template, ng-container approach.
We move all the individual components logic into their own components. The reasons I recommend ng-template is because you have easy control of @Input and @Output compared to dynamically rendered components. So we can render conditionally the component, as well as communicate data between the components with ease.
For the ng-container I have a property template which by default has the first template. We also use the directive *ngTemplateOutlet to render the component (which dynamically changes) then we pass the context as item: this so inside the template, when we do let-item="item" this property item will contain the this (context) of the component, so we can access the properties and methods.
I have also added methods and passing properties, from the parent to child for your reference.
Full Code:
App.html
<hello
  name="Consider App Component as Chart component loaded in Background"
></hello>
<div *ngIf="slideIn" @inOutPaneAnimation>
  <ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: { item: this }"
  ></ng-container>
</div>
<button (click)="Onclick('1')">Icon 1</button>
<button (click)="Onclick('2')">Icon 2</button>
<button (click)="slideIn = false">close</button>

<ng-template #one let-item="item">
  <app-component1
    [inputProp]="item.display"
    (outputEvent)="item.outputEmit($event)"
  ></app-component1>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #two let-item="item">
  <app-component2
    [inputProp]="item.display"
    (outputEvent)="item.outputEmit($event)"
  ></app-component2>
</ng-template>

App.ts
import { animate, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
import { Component, TemplateRef, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Component1Component } from './component1/component1.component';
import { Component2Component } from './component2/component2.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('inOutPaneAnimation', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }), //apply default styles before animation starts
        animate(
          '750ms ease-in-out',
          style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' })
        ),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' }), //apply default styles before animation starts
        animate(
          '600ms ease-in-out',
          style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('one') one!: TemplateRef<Component1Component>;
  @ViewChild('two') two!: TemplateRef<Component2Component>;
  template: TemplateRef<any> = this.one;
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  slideIn = false;
  display;

  Onclick(str) {
    this.slideIn = true;
    this.display = str;
    switch (str) {
      case '2':
        this.template = this.two;
        break;
      default:
        this.template = this.one;
        break;
    }
  }

  outputEmit(event: any) {
    alert(`from child ${event}`);
  }
}

Sample child component
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  template: `Component 1 opened as icon 1 is clicked - {{inputProp}}<br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <button (click)="clickEvent()"> click</button>`,
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {
  @Input() inputProp!: string;
  @Output() outputEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  clickEvent() {
    this.outputEvent.emit('Component1Component');
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

@narenmurli Thanks, This one is good approach. But as I mentioned I have 20-30 icons so I need to declare 20-30 viewChild reference variable in chart component and also it will increase switch case statement as well, can we optimize this bit more ? like by using array of obj for icons/components iterating ngFor and load it ?
Because it is not good practice I think to declare 20 view-child reference in one single  component.

@JayGajjar just use view children instead stackblitz is this ok?

@narenmurli ViewChildren is okay, but can we make comparison of icon click to reference var with unique ID instead array index ?(if its possible)
I mean if someone puts new component in between template/component listing in HTML then it breaks the mapping component with icons and by comparing index it will open wrong component.
